# Between IDispatchOperationSelector.SelectOperation and ServiceAuthenticationManager.Authenticate

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm writing a wcf service that needs to cope with a bespoke legacy message format (xml). When I first parse the incoming xml it is in an IDispatchOperationSelector, in the SelectOperation method.

The first thing I do is validate the xml against an xsd to ensure the incoming message is in the correct format. If it fails this validation, I WAS throwing an XmlSchemaValidationException and catching it in an IErrorHandler implementation, with the intention of returning a 400 - Bad Request error to the client.

Unfortunately, in the ProvideFault method of the IErrorHandler the OperationContext.Current is null. I think this is because the OperationSelector is a part of, or gets called before, OperationContext.Current creation. So instead of throwing the error in the OperationSelector, I decided to return the string "error" in the Operation Selector and set the message.Headers.Action to "error" as well, and add the required exception to the message properties, and then throw it after the creation of the operation context.

The problem is that the next extension point in my code to be hit is the ServiceAuthenticationManager.Authenticate method. If I check the message.Headers.Action and find error, and then throw that error in this method, it is swallowed by the framework and the error delivered to my error handler is "User not authenticated" which I suppose makes sense.

So I guess my question is, is there a point of extension in WCF that will allow me to throw this error between these two methods?

Answer (score 2):

Ok. wrong approach. What I had to do was throw the error in the OperationSelector and then in the ErrorHandler ProvideFault method,  ref Message fault is null, so I used the following code..

```
if (error is XmlSchemaValidationException && fault == null)
{
   fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, new FaultException().CreateMessageFault() , "error");

    fault.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = new HttpResponseMessageProperty
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
        SuppressEntityBody = true
    };
    return;
}
```

and that achieved my aim.

Hope this helps someone.
)